# Python Syntax Error in if statment

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Hey guys I'm programming using Python and I keep getting a syntax error in the main function.  After the if statement,
"if points >= 9 <= 51:" Python tells me that the colon is a syntax error.  I've written python code similar to this assignment and I can't seem to find the problem.  Can anyone help me?

Thanks it'll be much appreciated.

```
def variable(points):
if points >= 9 <= 51:
    print('Valid Points')
else:
    print('Invalid Points')

return points

def main():
points = int(input('Enter how many points you scored: ')
if points >= 9 <= 51:
    points = variable(points)
else:
    points = variable(points)

main()
```

Comment: `if points >= 9 <= 51:` is not an assignment, it's a comparison. This line of the code is correct, though it is probably not what you want. For example, it will evaluate to `true` if points is `100`, because `9` is always smaller than `51`. You probably want `if 9 <= points <= 51:`.

Comment: Please check the docs about the differente between `input()` and `raw_input()`. I highly doubt you want to allow users to enter arbitrary python expressions!

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax and indentation is a little off. Try

```
>>> def variable(points):
...     if 9<= points<= 51:
...          print('Valid Points')
...     else:
...         print('Invalid Points')
...
...
>>> variable(34)
Valid Points
```

and same goes for your `def main():` and also there is a missing paranthesis in

```
points = int(input('Enter how many points you scored: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the inequality problem, you forgot a trailing `)`:

```
points = int(input('Enter how many points you scored: ')
```

Comment: ahhhh now that was the problem... I guess I wasn't paying close attencion.  Thanks a lot guys, It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is wrong and missing paranthesis.

```
def variable(points):
    if points >= 9 <= 51:
        print('Valid Points')
    else:
        print('Invalid Points')

    return points

def main():
    points = int(input('Enter how many points you scored: '))
    if points >= 9 <= 51:
        points = variable(points)
    else:
        points = variable(points)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close a paren.

```
points = int(input('Enter how many points you scored: '))
```